# how do i get the user id and be able to display the user credentials when user registers using express js and mysql and react native

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, api, express

I am having a difficult time being able to get the user id and credentials and displaying them when they log in, I will show you my code so you can better understand where I stand.

this is the server side(I am using expressjs mysql to store the user )

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: ''

})

//User Signup, post on to database
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {

//check to see if user exist already
const check = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?';

//no two users should have the same email
db.query(check, [req.body.email], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("user already exist")

    //hash the password
    //s0/\/\P4$$w0rD
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    //add user to db
    const q = "INSERT INTO users (`name`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.name, req.body.email, hash]
    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err)
        const userid = data.insertId;
        return res.status(200).json("user has been registered",userid)
    })
})`
```

I want to be able to get the user id when they register so I can be able to display the user credentials like name and bio and be able to store it in a storage so they wont have to log back in when they close the app

I have tried endless youtube videos and read the documentation but it I still cant figure it out so that is why I am calling on the people for help